# Android Compilation Error

Tags: android

I have an android application. I am facing some problems while compile. So where is the problem. Please help me. Sorry for my poor english.

Here is the erro:

```
Information:Using javac 1.6.0_65 to compile java sources
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'cycle4it_android'
Information:Compilation completed with 1 error and 6 warnings in 2 sec
Information:1 error
Information:6 warnings
Warning:java: Note: /Users/m/Projects/navico/mobile/android/cycle4it_android/src/com/cubicasa/cycle4it/DonateActivity.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Warning:java: Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
/Users/m/Projects/navico/mobile/android/cycle4it_android/src/com/cubicasa/cycle4it/DonateActivity.java
    Warning:Warning:line (417)java: /Users/m/Projects/navico/mobile/android/cycle4it_android/src/com/cubicasa/cycle4it/DonateActivity.java:417: warning: [deprecation] Notification(int,java.lang.CharSequence,long) in android.app.Notification has been deprecated
    Warning:Warning:line (419)java: /Users/m/Projects/navico/mobile/android/cycle4it_android/src/com/cubicasa/cycle4it/DonateActivity.java:419: warning: [deprecation] setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent) in android.app.Notification has been deprecated
/Users/m/Projects/navico/mobile/android/cycle4it_android/src/com/cubicasa/cycle4it/SignupActivity.java
    Error:Error:line (28)java: /Users/m/Projects/navico/mobile/android/cycle4it_android/src/com/cubicasa/cycle4it/SignupActivity.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setPluginsEnabled(boolean)
location: class android.webkit.WebSettings
/Users/m/Projects/navico/mobile/android/cycle4it_android/src/com/cubicasa/cycle4it/SubmitActivity.java
    Warning:Warning:line (106)java: /Users/m/Projects/navico/mobile/android/cycle4it_android/src/com/cubicasa/cycle4it/SubmitActivity.java:106: warning: [deprecation] Notification(int,java.lang.CharSequence,long) in android.app.Notification has been deprecated
    Warning:Warning:line (107)java: /Users/m/Projects/navico/mobile/android/cycle4it_android/src/com/cubicasa/cycle4it/SubmitActivity.java:107: warning: [deprecation] setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent) in android.app.Notification has been deprecated
```

Here is my signup activity:

```
public class SignupActivity extends Activity {
WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("http://beta.cycle4it.com/register");

}
```

Here is my Submit activity:

```
public class SubmitActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView distance, userid, purpose, email, type;
Button submit;
NotificationManager nm;
static final int uniqueId=12;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.submit);
    new CreateUser().execute();
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
    userid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usrid);
    String distanceink = String.valueOf(Constant.totalDistanceinKm);
    String userId = Constant.idusr;
    distance.setText(distanceink);
    userid.setText(userId);
    nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.cancel(uniqueId);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);

}

class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        String distanceink = String.valueOf(Constant.totalDistanceinKm);
        String useridc = String.valueOf(Constant.idusr);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String url = "http://......./api/POST/donate/data";
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        // httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        // httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> namevalpair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            namevalpair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("km", distanceink));
            namevalpair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", useridc));
            namevalpair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("purpose", "1"));
            namevalpair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",
                    "moudud.hassan@cubicasa.fi"));
            namevalpair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "1"));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                    namevalpair, HTTP.UTF_8);
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse httpresponse = client.execute(httppost);
            int responsecode = httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.d("responsenummmm", "submit" + responsecode);
            // Log.d("httpresponseeeee", httpresponse.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    String body="Good job: "+Constant.distance+" biked so";
    String title="Cycle4it";
    Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.nf, body, System.currentTimeMillis());
    n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, body, pIntent);
    n.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    nm.notify(uniqueId, n);
    this.finish();
}

}
```

Comment: i guess your lint is not working.

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: these are just lint warnings. Put cursor on line which is showing error and press F2 key. It will show popup. Click on "Disable lint check for this project"

Comment: @Haresh I updated my question. Please check.

Comment: What is on line 28 of `SignupActivity` ?

Comment: @fiddler it is "webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `setPluginsEnabled` method that you're trying to call on a `WebSettings` doesn't seem to exist (cf [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html)).

There is a `setPluginState` method but it's going to be deprecated and should not be used anymore.

> Plugins will not be supported in future, and should not be used.

Answer (score 2):

try to replace this peace of code

```
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true)
```

To

```
webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```